# Android - getIdentifier() throws Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, exception, android-resources

I'm making a simple scoring system for a minesweeper clone and I keep getting the Resources$NotFoundException when it crashes. I'm pretty sure it's the getIdentifier function that's causing it and I've had nothing but trouble with this function in the past. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
private void doScoring()
{
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("scores", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int score = (int) Math.ceil(1000/this.getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("time"));
    int[] scores = new int[10];
    String[] names = new String[10];
    int newOffset = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(sp.getInt("s"+i,999)>score&&newOffset==0)
        {
            newOffset++;
            names[i] = "Prompted Name";
            scores[i] = score;
        }
        scores[i] = sp.getInt("s"+(i-newOffset), 999);
        names[i] = sp.getString("n"+(i-newOffset), "No Score");
        ((TextView) this.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("score_name_"+(i+1), "id", "edu.laura.omc_prototype"))).setText(scores[i]);
        ((TextView) this.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("score_"+(i+1), "id", "edu.laura.omc_prototype"))).setText(names[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the resource file where you are defining all of these `id` resources that you are trying to look up. Also, what value of `i` are you crashing on?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm crashing on `i = 0`.
![My Resources](http://a.pomf.se/ilbzrt.PNG)![The Error](http://a.pomf.se/rugumu.PNG)

Comment: I haven't tried using `getIdentifier()` to get a widget ID. Given the small number, it is probably simpler for you to just set up a `TextView[]` data structure and get them by index, rather than using `getResources().getIdentifier()`.